# Ruby to_yaml utf8 string

Tags: ruby, utf-8, yaml, to-yaml

How can I make ruby to_yaml method to store utf8 strings with original signs but not escape sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a really bad idea as I'm sure YAML has its reasons for encoding the characters as it does, but it doesn't seem too hard to undo:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'yaml/encoding'

text = "Ça va bien?"

puts text.to_yaml(:Encoding => :Utf8) # => --- "\xC3\x87a va bien?"
puts YAML.unescape(YAML.dump(text)) # => --- "Ça va bien?"
```

Comment: It was reasonable in the past to use ASCII encoding by default, but this is not the case now. And the manual says: "YAML streams are encoded using the set of printable Unicode characters, either in UTF-8 or UTF-16.". So I think it's just a limitation in Ruby's library, to_yaml should return UTF-8 by default. Otherwise it's really burdensome to modify those YAML with an editor.

Comment: dump sometimes returns you a binary type: YAML.unescape(YAML.dump("sú")) -> --- !binary | c8O6

Answer (score 7):

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler='psych'
'Résumé'.to_yaml # => "--- Résumé\n...\n"
```

Ruby ships with two YAML engines: syck and psych. Syck is old and not maintained, but it is default in 1.9.2, so one needs to switch to psych. Psych dumps UTF-8 strings in UTF-8.

Comment: Note that this answer only works for Ruby 1.9.3 (where Psych is already the default). The above code does not work for Ruby 1.9.2 (`no such file to load -- psych`).

Comment: …unless you first install the `psych` gem.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout Ya2Yaml at [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ya2yaml/).

Comment: You can find an updated version w/ gemspec here: https://github.com/afunai/ya2yaml

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby 1.9.3+, this is not a problem: the default YAML engine is Psych, which supports UTF-8 by default.

For Ruby 1.9.2- you need to install the `psych` gem and require it *before you require yaml*:

```ruby
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
#=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'psych'
#=> true
irb(main):003:0> YAML::ENGINE
#=> #<YAML::EngineManager:0x00000001a1f642 @yamler="syck">
irb(main):004:0> "ça va?".to_yaml
#=> "--- \"\\xC3\\xA7a va?\"\n"
```

```ruby
irb(main):001:0> require 'psych' # gem install psych
#=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'yaml'
#=> true
irb(main):003:0> YAML::ENGINE
#=> #<YAML::EngineManager:0x00000001a1f828 @yamler="psych">
irb(main):004:0> "ça va bien!".to_yaml
#=> "--- ça va bien!\n...\n"
```

Alternatively, set the `yamler` as Evgeny suggests (assuming you have installed the `psych` gem):

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
#=> true
irb(main):002:0> YAML::ENGINE.yamler
#=> "syck"
irb(main):003:0> "ça va?".to_yaml
#=> "--- \"\\xC3\\xA7a va?\"\n"
irb(main):004:0> YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'
#=> "psych"
irb(main):005:0> "ça va".to_yaml
#=> "--- ça va\n...\n"
```