# The simplest way to puts sterling-pound in ruby from a yaml file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a yaml file with a pound-sterling sign on it -

```
amount: "£50"
```

when I access the symbol it return the following:

```
"┬ú50"
```

I am using hashie:mash to load and access my yaml... ideas are welcome, haven't found anything on the webs that give a straight forward solution (or at least one that works for me)

Comment: see if you can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158072/ruby-to-yaml-utf8-string)

Comment: Where is it returning that value *to*? It looks like you're trying to output a UTF-8 character as US-ASCII; Ruby strings are UTF-8 by default. What are `Encoding.default_internal` and `Encoding.default_external` set to?

Comment: see if you can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158072/ruby-to-yaml-utf8-string)

Comment: external is CP850, internal is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external encoding is your issue; Ruby is assuming that any data read from external files is CP-850, rather than UTF-8.

You can solve this a few ways:

1. Set `Encoding.default_external ='utf-8'`. This will tell Ruby to read files as UTF-8 by default.
2. Explicitly read your file as UTF-8, via `open('file.yml', 'r:utf-8')`
3. Convert your string to UTF-8 before you pass it to your YAML parser:

You can do this via `String#force_encoding`, which tells Ruby to reinterpret the raw bytes with a different encoding:

```
 text = open("file.yml").read
 text.force_encoding("utf-8")
 YAML.load text
```

Comment: Encoding.default_external ='utf-8' did the trick! ty so much!!! It is weird tho why, I am using the exact same version of gems/ruby but Ubuntu this does not occur but moving to windows I have to explicitly state the line above... either way, it looks good! thanks again!!